# mRNA Covid-19 Vaccine Safety in Pregnant Persons

Tags: style

> mRNA Covid-19 Vaccine Safety in Pregnant Persons
> BACKGROUND
> Many pregnant persons in the United States are receiving messenger RNA (mRNA) coronavirus disease 2019 (Covid-19) vaccines, but data are limited on their safety in pregnancy.
> [image]

Source: [New England Journal of Medicine](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2104983?query=featured_home)

It appears to me that "pregnant persons", rather than the usual "pregnant women", tends to impress the reader by deliberately using alliteration.

Does "pregnant persons" sound bookish to you? Is the alliteration natural and successful to you?

Comment: It sounds to me like 'taking political correctness to ridiculous extremes'.

Comment: What does this thin pretext for conservative troll-bait have to do with English Language Learners?

Comment: A pre-teenage girl may become pregnant, yet not be old enough to be called a 'woman'. Anyway, perhaps T.T.Shimabukuro is not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a combination of being strictly correct and politically correct. A person who was assigned female at birth and has all the requisite parts to become pregnant and bear a baby may identify as a man, or as "something other than a woman." Therefore to say "pregnant women" would exclude this pregnant man.

It is certainly possible that a study would want to exclude such pregnant men, or would want to include *only* them, due to their unique situation—especially if they have progressed at all in their physical transition. But this study did not exclude such men, so it refers to all "pregnant persons" rather than just "pregnant women."

The usage of "persons" instead of "people" does sound bookish and unnatural, but I believe it is the proper terminology and that you will find similar usage in legal documents, etc.

Comment: I think 'pregnant person' is absolutely fine, and may even have the advantage of annoying people who see 'political correctness' everywhere.